# Video file isn't loading, is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm currently working through a boot camp( very early stages of my coding journey). I've been able to build text and image links without an issue. I've tried multiple different ways to include a video on one of my pages but my test page is just showing a blank blacked out video window.

This is the format my boot camp recommended which has gotten me the furthest (result is a blank video window)

```
<video controls autoplay loop src="videos/happydog.mp4"></video>
```

I've also tried the code below but with my own file references. This didn't even load a video window/file.

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
<source src="resources/sample/sample1.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
```

I've tried downloading the smallest available size of the video I'm using. I've ran my code through multiple validations and it's not picking up on any other errors.

My live server is with Microsoft Edge and I'm using Visual Studio.

I'm stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: You must close your video tag with a `</video>`... See the example at: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video).

Answer (score 1):

You did not provided src code but below i collected in a list some popular mistakes,errors that you can check

1. Check the file path: Ensure correct reference to the video file.

```html
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src="path/to/your/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

2. Verify video format: Use MP4, WebM, or Ogg formats for wider
   support.
3. Check browser support: Ensure your browser supports the video
   format.
4. Verify server configuration: Ensure server allows video file
   serving.
5. Test with different video: Try using another video file to isolate
   the issue.
6. Test on different browsers: Check if the problem is specific to one
   browser.
7. Look for errors: Check browser console for video-related error
   messages.

Comment: Not providing markup is a reason to close the question, not answer it. Otherwise, your answer becomes a wild guess as to the solution.